# mysql: value can be "null", but not must be "specific_value"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT group.active, group.desc,
group.group_id, hide_group.hide,
hide_group.user_id
FROM group 
LEFT JOIN hide_group ON
     group.group_id=hide_group.group_id
WHERE group.active=1 
AND hide_group.user_id != 'test' 
OR hide_group.user_id IS NULL   
ORDER BY hide_group`.`user_id`  DESC
```

This completely ignores the active row for some reason? If I remove

> and hide_group.user_id!='test'

It takes active=1 into account, but does not return right values. If I examine the first query, everything would be ok if the active condition would be taken into account. Help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the parentheses in the correct way when you deal with "and" and "or" together.

Comment: Oh... I was pulling my hair out for nothing. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

table name `group`, field name `desc` would not help